# gnuplot: overlay order of multiple plots in dumb terminal

Tags: ascii, gnuplot

I have quite "oscilating data" (timestamp value1). Therefore i added another column containing a moving average, so the data looks like (timestamp value1 value2). I use the dumb terminal. The idea is to have the oscilating data shown "with dots" and "on top" the average line "with lines". Unfotunately, my result looks like this:

```
  3 ++---+---+----+---+----+---+----+--##----+---+----+----+---+----+---+----+---+----+---+----+---+----+---+---++
    +        +        +.       #       ##        +         +        +        +        +        + raw data   .    +
    |                          #      ..#     ..  . .                            10 minute moving average ###### |
2.8 ++                .        #      .##       #   # .                                                         ++
    |               .. .       #       .#       #.  #                                                            |
    |   .           #          #.      ##   .. ..  .##   .                                                       |
2.6 ++              #       .  # .    .## .    ##.  ##                                                          ++
    |               #..  .     # .    .## ..  #.#.# ##                                                           |
    |      .        #  ## #   .#      .## .   .#...... .                                                         |
2.4 ++    . .       # ### #  . #.. #. #.. #.. .#. #.##  .                                                       ++
    |    ....      ..##.. # .# ##..#..# # #.#.. .... #  .#                                                       |
    |    . ... .   .###.####.#.## #.#.. # ...# .   # .  .#                                                       |
2.2 ++ . #.###.    #..###.## ..#..##..  ..#....    .  ...#                                                      ++
    |   .###..##. ...# #....##..# ... ..... ..    .  ...##                                                       |
    |   ....#.#. ..# .... .#....#.##..  ..          .....#                                                       |
  2 ++ ... ...#.# ... ......   .# . .   ..            .. #                                                      ++
    |  .  .   ......  .    ..   .    .   .   .     .     #                                                       |
1.8 ++  . .  .# ..          ..    .    .                 #                                                      ++
    |  ..     .....                                      #                                                       |
    |           .          .                             #                                                       |
1.6 ++          .                                        #                                                      ++
    |                                                    #                                                .      |
    |                                                    #                                                       |
1.4 ++                                                   #                            .                    .    ++
    |                                                    #  .       .                 .   .         .    ...     |
    |                                                    . . .  .    .... .. . . . .. .#.   .  . ...   . ...     |
1.2 ++                                                   .........  .................... .....   ... ... ..     ++
    |                                                    ..................................................      |
    +        +        +        +        +        +         .     ..... .     + . . .  +........... ......        +
  1 ++---+---+----+---+----+---+----+---+----+---+----+----+---.----+---+----+---+----+---+----+---+----+---+---++
  11:00    12:00    13:00    14:00    15:00    16:00     17:00    18:00    19:00    20:00    21:00    22:00    23:00
```

The average data is still quite oscilating, but that's not the point. There are several places in the graph, where the #-line isn't visible anymore. The used plot command is

```
plot 'data.dat' using 1:2 with dots title 'raw data', '' using 1:3 with lines title '10 minute moving average'
```

As you can see, the average line is often overlaid by the raw data. All my attempts (change order, linewidth...) were not successfull. Only when using "with lines" in both cases, the order matters. But i don't want the raw data to be plotted as line.

If you want to reproduce my issue, you can use

```
set terminal dumb
plot cos(x) w dots, abs(cos(x)) w lines
```

This will produce

```
   1 +###--------..---+-----##--------...--------##-----+---..--------###+
     +# #       .  .  +    #  #      . + .      #  #    +  cos(x)   . # #+
 0.8 #+  #     .    #     #   #      .   .      #   # abs(cos(x)) ######+#
     |    #    #    .     #    #     #    #    #    #     .    #    #    |
 0.6 ++   #    .     .    #     #   .     .    #     #   .     .    #   ++
     |    #   .      #   #      #   #      #  #      #   #      .   #    |
 0.4 ++    #  #      .  #       #  .       .  #       #  .       #  #   ++
     |     # .        # #       #  .       .  #       #  #       . #     |
 0.2 ++     ##        . #        # #        # #       # .        # #    ++
     |      #.         ##        #.         .#         ##        .#      |
   0 ++                .                               .                ++
     |      .                    .           .                    .      |
-0.2 ++                 .                             .                 ++
     |     .                    .             .                    .     |
-0.4 ++                 .                             .                 ++
     |    .              .      .             .      .              .    |
-0.6 ++                                                                 ++
     |    .               .    .               .    .               .    |
-0.8 .+  .                .   .                 .   .                .  +.
     +. .             +    .  .        +        .  .    +             . .+
  -1 +...-------------+-----..---------+---------..-----+-------------...+
    -10              -5                0                5                10
```

But the result i expect should look like this (all dots are overlaied by #)

```
   1 +###--------##---+-----##--------###--------##-----+---##--------###+
     +# #       #  #  +    #  #      # + #      #  #    +  cos(x)   . # #+
 0.8 #+  #     #    #     #   #      #   #      #   # abs(cos(x)) ######+#
     |    #    #    #     #    #     #    #    #    #     #    #    #    |
 0.6 ++   #    #     #    #     #   #     #    #     #   #     #    #   ++
     |    #   #      #   #      #   #      #  #      #   #      #   #    |
 0.4 ++    #  #      #  #       #  #       #  #       #  #       #  #   ++
     |     # #        # #       #  #       #  #       #  #       # #     |
 0.2 ++     ##        # #        # #        # #       # #        # #    ++
     |      ##         ##        ##         ##         ##        ##      |
   0 ++                #                               #                ++
     |      .                    .           .                    .      |
-0.2 ++                 .                             .                 ++
     |     .                    .             .                    .     |
-0.4 ++                 .                             .                 ++
     |    .              .      .             .      .              .    |
-0.6 ++                                                                 ++
     |    .               .    .               .    .               .    |
-0.8 .+  .                .   .                 .   .                .  +.
     +. .             +    .  .        +        .  .    +             . .+
  -1 +...-------------+-----..---------+---------..-----+-------------...+
    -10              -5                0                5                10
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem you see.  I get the desired plot with no modification required.    In gnuplot the elements of the 'plot' command are always executed in order, so it is mysterious how anything in the first element could overwrite something in the second element.   The best I can guess is that your problem arises from plotting one element "with dots" and the other one "with lines".  Try using `with points pt '.'` and `with points pt'#'`.  Possibly it would help to do `set sample 999`.

Comment: @Ethan Ok, i think it is a bug. I use gnuplot Version 4.2 patchlevel 6. Also your suggestion do not work with this version. Quite old, i know. Tried Version 5.2 patchlevel 2 on a different system and it just worked. Thanks for your answer as it pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: I quickly checked and could reproduce it up to gnuplot versions <=5.0.6. Probably it was fixed with 5.2. But why on earth are you working with such an old version? 4.2 !?